# Unwanted space and arrow in accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am creating a vertical accordion menu. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/jpcb7w5y/1/) is code what I had done so far. Two problems I am facing.

1. There is unwanted space between border and menu. It is for all `li` elements i.e for menu and sub menu items also.
2. And arrow is showing for submenu also after having following code

`#menunav li > a:only-child:before { content: '';}`

I trying to put arrow image for menu that having sub menus. e.g. **Item 1** is having sub menus so **Item 1** should have arrow not its sub menus items. And also if I have **Sub-Item 1 a** of **Item 1**, sub menus like below:

```
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a>
        <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 aa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 bb</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 cc</a></li>
    </ul>
        </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Then **Item 1** and **Sub-Item 1 a** will have arrow etc.

I am not able to remove that space and putting arrow for menu that having submenu.

Can someone please suggest what should I change in `jquery` and `css` so that I can get that properly working?

Comment: use http://cssreset.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `#menunav`, `ul` into `li` padding to 0

```
#menunav, #menunav ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or just reset the padding:

```
* {
    padding: 0
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jpcb7w5y/4/)

**Update**

If you want to remove submenu arrow, do this:

Example:

```
#menunav li ul li a:before {
    background: none;
}
```

updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jpcb7w5y/10/

Comment: @ Radonirina Maminiaina: Hey thanks. The space is now removed. But how do I set the arrow to menu that having submenus only?

Comment: What do you mean by setting the arrow to menu?

Comment: Now in my demo arrow image is showing to submenu's also. I just want that arrow should be only to the menus that will have submenu.

Comment: i think you have wrongly understand what OP want. Click the item1, you can see sub-items with arrow. OP dont want that arrow.

Comment: @ Radonirina Maminiaina: if I have sub menus e.g. **Sub-Item 1 a** like this http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/jpcb7w5y/11/ . then it should behave like Item and Sub-Item. means  **Sub-Item 1 a** should have arrow and show submenus. Its not working properly. should the jquery also needs to be changed?

Comment: @ Radonirina Maminiaina: I guess css also needs to be change, to get arrow for  **Sub-Item 1 a** as it is having sub menus and little left space for its sub menus to look like tree structure.

Comment: You need to change your css to do this! :)

Answer (score 2):

**CSS**

```
#menunav{padding:0}
```

since we need to clear the default style of the `ul` element

Comment: @ vas: Hey thanks. The space is now removed. But how do I set the arrow to menu that having submenus only?

Comment: @ vas: space of main menus and border is removed with above code. Its not removing space between border and submenus.

Comment: @kiran  `ul{padding:0}` add this it will remove all spaces

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

CSS:

```
#menunav {
    padding: 0px;
}

#menunav li ul {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I think your `<ul>` has its own padding. Hope this helps.

Edited:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jpcb7w5y/5/)

I you want that the arrows only appears to the main menu that have the sub menu, I have this quick solution for that. Why not try putting some class on the `<a>` for the main menu. Hope this works.

Instead of:

```
#menunav li a:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url("http://transparency.perkinswill.com/content/images/right-arrow.png") no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

Why not:

```
#menunav .main:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url("http://transparency.perkinswill.com/content/images/right-arrow.png") no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: @ John : Hey thanks. The space is now removed. But how do I set the arrow to menu that having submenus only?

Comment: @ John: if i am having sub menus for **Sub-Item 1 a** like here http://jsfiddle.net/kirankapur/jpcb7w5y/9/ . Its not showing arrow to **Sub-Item 1 a** as it is having sub menus. I guess solution should be general. thanks